# Delete lines containing pattern at the end of line

Tags: sed

Quite certainly I miss something basic. My file contains lines like

```
fooLOCATION=sdfmsvdnv

fooLOCATION=

barLOCATION=sadssf

barLOCATION=
```

and I want to delete all lines ending with `LOCATION=`.

```
sed -i '/LOCATION=$/d' file
```

does not do, it deletes nothing, and I have tried endless variations, but I don't get it. What inline sed command can do this?

Comment: good stuff below, but first check that there are not trailing white-space with `cat -vet file` You'll see `$` marker for end of line, `^I` for tabs and, if they exist, `^M` for `\r` (DOS line endings). Good luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two approaches here, either print all non-matching lines with

```
sed -in '/LOCATION=$/!p' file
```

or delete all matching names with

```
sed -i '/LOCATION=$/d' file
```

The first uses the **n** command line option to suppress the default action of printing the line.  We then test for lines that end in `LOCATION=` and invert the pattern (only keeping those that don't match).  When we get a desirable line, we print it with the p option.

The second looks for lines matching the end of line pattern, and deletes those that do.

Your file contains blank lines, and both of these keep those.  If we don't want to keep those, we can change the first option to

```
sed -in '/^$/!{/LOCATION=$/!p}' file
```

which first checks if a line is not empty, and only bothers checking if it should be printed if it isn't empty.  We can modify the second option to

```
sed -i '/^$/d;/LOCATION=$/d' file
```

which deletes blank lines and then checks about deleting the other pattern.

---

We can modify the options to work with different line ending by specifying the difference in the pattern.  The difference between line endings on Unix/Linux (`\n`) and Windows (`\r\n`) is the presence of an extra carriage return on Windows.  Modifying the four commands above to accept either, we get

1. `sed -in '/LOCATION=\r\{0,1\}$/!p' file`
2. `sed -i '/LOCATION=\r\{0,1\}$/d' file`
3. `sed -in '/^\r\{0,1\}$/!{/LOCATION=\r\{0,1\}$/!p}' file`
4. `sed -i '/^\r\{0,1\}$/d;/LOCATION=\r\{0,1\}$/d' file`

Note that in each of these we allow an optional `\r` before the end of line.  We use the curly bracket notation, as sed does not support the question mark optional quantifier in normal mode (using the **r** option to GNU sed for enabling extended regular expressions, we can replace `\{0,1\}` with `?`).

---

On a Windows shell, all of the options above require double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Thank you! Though @user454038 gave the hint (I didn't know that `file` was generated in windows), the removal of the carriage return did it. And thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Your command does work for me:

```
$ sed -i '/LOCATION=$/d' file
```

Results, viewed using `cat`:

```
$ cat file
fooLOCATION=sdfmsvdnv


barLOCATION=sadssf
```

### Note

If a file has non-Unix line endings such as files from Windows with DOS-formatted line-endings, it can be a reason for failure. A typical remedy is to use `dos2unix`:

```
$ dos2unix file
```

This converter fixes the newline issues, so that `file` will now have Unix-style line endings. Sed should now properly recognize those line endings, so retry your sed command and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! As I did not know from the beginning, `file` was generated in windows, so there was a carriage return that had to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/LOCATION=\s*$/d' file
```

This deletes the line if `LOCATION=` is at the end of the line or if there is any optional white space following the pattern.